# Django server close on closing browser tab

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-3.x

I want to close the django server (CMD) when closing browser tab. After some hours of research, I tried the codes below.

- I added `onbeforeunload` javascript inside my header template so that every page that contains my web app will have that event handler.

```
{% block js %}  
<script>
//close ui on tab click
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
$.ajax({ // Ajax call
type: "POST",
url: "closeui",
success: function(k){ 
alert('Good bye'); 
return false;
});

    return "Do you really want to close?";
};

</script>
{% endblock js %}
```

- For routing, I added URL as `closeui`.
- In views, I created a `closeui` function which will perform closing the CMD.

```
def closeui():
    import os
    from win32com.client import GetObject

    WMI = GetObject('winmgmts:')
    processes = WMI.InstancesOf('Win32_Process')

    for p in WMI.ExecQuery('select * from Win32_Process where Name="cmd.exe"'):
        print("Killing PID:", p.Properties_('ProcessId').Value)
        os.system("taskkill /pid "+str(p.Properties_('ProcessId').Value))
    return True
```

I didn't get my desired results. Can someone correct me where I went wrong?

Comment: Your JavaScript is broken: the close parenthesis and the close braces near the end of your first code sample is messed up.

Comment: Does your code have any submit button, can you share more info on what when wrong. As we have cracked similar problem we can see if that help.